# Chrome Extension: why i have this error in console of the "background page"?

Tags: javascript, api, console, google-chrome-extension

I don't understand but it seems like not recognize api's google chrome, maybe.

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "First Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "The first extensione tha I made",
    "permissions":["contextMenus"],
    "background_page": "background_page.html"
}
```

Background page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Background Page</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript (script.js):

```
if (window.webkitNotifications) {
  console.log("Notifications are supported!");
}
else {
  console.log("Notifications are not supported for this Browser/OS version yet.");
}
/////////// BROWSER CONTEXT MENU ////////////////
var arr_context = ["all", "page", "frame", "selection", "link", "editable", "image", "video", "audio"];
for(i=0; i<arr_context.length; i++){
    var title = arr_context[i];
    var menu1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"type":"normal", "title":"Menu "+title, "contexts":arr_context, "onclick":callBack });
}


function callBack(info, tab){ console.log(info.menuItemId+"; URL: "+tab.url); }
```

Function "callBack(info, tab)" don't write anything. In background page there's an error, ERROR is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined`.

The all files are only these.

OK, I solved, read the mistake was made, on internet because I was not accessing the page 
from Extension Tab, but than double click on background_page.html.... Is' much heavy it? -.-°

Comment: If you open the `background_page` console from `chrome://extensions` is `chrome.contextMenues` defined and can you manually call `chrome.contextMenues.create()`?

Comment: '
**chrome.contextMenues()**
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'contextMenues'

**chrome**
Object

**chrome.contextMenues.create();**
TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined
'

Comment: Just `chrome.contextMenus` not `chrome.contextMenus()`. Update: Oops I had a typo in my first comment where I spelled `contextMenus` wrong. Try it again.

Comment: chrome.contextMenus -> undefined

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has already been stated, if you still find that chrome.contextMenus is 'undefined', remember to uninstall-reinstall your extension! There may be some odd caching occurring; some things update while your developing (ie. you can change code then see changes on retriggering your extension), and others require a complete reinstall - HTH.